# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Email Export

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, export-to-excel, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have to export Emails activities from `Dynamics CRM 2011` to import them on `CRM 2016`.

The problem is that for some fields like (Cc, Bcc) I have more than one data and when I export datas to `Excel`, it creates me Merged Cell for the sender when they are more than 1 Cc.

- I can't import them to 2016 because of empty lines.
- I would like to have all recipients in one cell.

**Example:**

I have 3  lines for :

```
toto@toto.com
titi@titi.com
tata@tata.com
```

Instead of 1 line and all datas in the same cell :

```
toto@toto.com ; titi@titi.com ; tata@tata.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting more emails in one field separated with semicolon as those fields are party list fields which can contain more than one activity party type of record, which can be any activity related entity or just an email value.

If you want to re-use the emails for import you will need some excel magic.

See this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-names-by-using-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-39f7b055-6b39-4cb5-9512-13cc19b3a807) for more info.

What you need to do is, to split the email columns based on delimiter semicolon, then move the column values, into new rows.